# How to add price and quantity details when adding a product to Amazon seller central Using Amazon MWS?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am using Amazon MWS Feeds API for adding products to Amazon seller central store. When I use an example from Amazon's [Feeds API Section Reference](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSFeedsApiReference._V388518764_.pdf), products added to the store without price. I've added the code below I used for adding product to Amazon seller central store.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>M_EXAMPLE_123456</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
        <SKU>TEST1234</SKU>
        <StandardProductID>
          <Type>ASIN</Type>
          <Value>B0EXAMPLEG</Value>
        </StandardProductID>
        <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
        <DescriptionData>
          <Title>Example Product Title</Title>
          <Brand>Example Product Brand</Brand>
          <Description>This is an example product description.</Description>
          <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
          <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
          <ItemType>example-item-type</ItemType>
        </DescriptionData>
        <ProductData>
          <Health>
            <ProductType>
              <HealthMisc>
                <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
                <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
              </HealthMisc>
            </ProductType>
          </Health>
        </ProductData>
    </Product>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

What's the cause of this issue and how can it be fixed, and how can I add `Quantity` in the above code?
I used this code from Amazon Feed API reference.

Comment: can u tell me what is the product type showing in seller central account. Is that MISC_OTHER????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to submit different xml files and feed types for product,price,inventory etc. You cannot send this information together in xml files to upload a product. But if you are using excel spreadsheets you can send all this information in a single file. you can refer this to know about spreadsheet upload. http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200203300